iOS Xcode 15.3 always return flutter_jailbreak_detection module not found
flutter_jailbreak_detection module not found.
I have tried to clean and reboot but noting changed
Under the file generated automatically.
Please help to solve out the problem.
flutter_jailbreak_detection module not found.
I have tried to clean and reboot but noting changed

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
